# TypeError: document.quoteform is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I have this pesky problem with my code that I think is a runtime error because it shows up when I run the program and actually stops it. I used an error console to show me where the error is, but I can't make sense of it. If anybody can point me in the right directions without giving me the answer I'd appreciate it. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     <!-- HIDE FROM INCOMPATIBLE BROWSERS
     function changeQuote() {
     quotes = new Array;
     quotes[0] = "Laughter is the best medicine.";
     quotes[1] = "Never look a gift horse in the mouth.";
     quotes[2] = "One good turn deserves another.";
     quotes[3] = "The early bird catches the worm.";
     quotes[4] = "Two is company, three is a crowd.";
     var newQuote = quotes[Math.round(Math.random()+quotes.length)];
     document.quoteform.quote.value = newQuote;
     }
     var tick = setInterval("changeQuote()");
     // STOP HIDING FROM INCOMPATIBLE BROWSERS -->
     </script>
     </head>
     <body>
     <form action=""name="">
     <input type="text" size="50" name="quote" /><br />
     </form>
     </body>
     </html>
```

I also have two image of the error console message:[image]

Comment: Why would `document.quoteform` be defined? I don't see any elements that have an id or a name of `quoteform`.

Comment: A tip: An object must exist before you can add properties to it.

Comment: That's what confuses me. So I assumed it must be something else. I can't make sense of it. That's why I came to the forum.

Comment: That makes more sense. I get right to it. Thanks